# processing dates in the future with java

Tags: java, android, datetime

I would like to figure out how to get the milliseconds remaining from a future date in java so that I can make a coundown timer, something like:

```
long countdowntimer = futuredate - system.currentTimeMillis();
```

Comment: `long countdowntimer = futuredate.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis();`

Comment: as i catch @ edmund Rojas he wants to counting in background of its app process?but he deserve -1 for Questioning style...

Comment: sorry I should have clarified, I guess what I should ask is how can I convert a generic date like for example If I know the users birthday is: Sat Feb 17 2012, how do I convert that to the futuredate variable, sorry again for not clarifying properly

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `futuredate`  is of type `Date`, you get a `long` representation using its `getTime()` method.

EDIT:

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
Date d = fmt.parse("Sat Feb 17 2012");
System.out.println((d.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis() )/1000 + " seconds till " + d );
```

Comment: sorry I should have clarified, I guess what I should ask is how can I convert a generic date like for example If I know the users birthday is: Sat Feb 17 2012, how do I convert that to the futuredate variable, sorry again for not clarifying properly

Comment: @EdmundRojas You can parse the Date using `SimpleDateFormat.parse(String)`

Comment: so would that parse even a generic string such as the example that I gave?

Answer (score 0):

In your questions you should **specifically ask your problem or mention the error** you are getting.. We are not interested what you "would like" to do... Anyways this may work for you... 
[`getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29)

For next time be more specific... #happyProgramming

**EDIT**
For ur second requirement you can use `Date(String s)` of java.util.Date class **(remember it is a deprecated approach)**, or more precisely use [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) class's `parse() method`, I would recommend the second approach..